# cannot access a structure membre

Tags: c, pointers, struct, scanf

## Code

I'm trying to create a program to manage a university, to do that I think of creating a `stuct` **student** and put another `struct` **branch** inside of it. this is what I've done, which is not working well

> **base.h**

```
#define DEG_SIZE 2
#define BRANCH_SIZE 5
struct Branch{
        char Departement;
        char Year;
    }b;
     typedef struct Branch _BRANCH;
_BRANCH branch[BRANCH_SIZE];
   struct Student_informations{
        char Stud_name;
        float deg[DEG_SIZE];
        char* Stud_year;
        char Payment_State;
        _BRANCH Stud_branch;
    }c;
    typedef struct Student_informations _STUDENT;
enum Departement
    { MATH,PHY, 
      CHY,GIO, 
      BIO,INFO
    };
enum Year
    { first,second,
      licence,master,
      doc
    };
enum Payment
    {
        TRUE,
        FALSE
    };
```

> **student.c**

```
/*<--------------SETUP-------------->*/

/*=============-MATH-=============*/
            //SMIA
    branch[0].Departement = MATH;
    branch[0].Year = first;

            //SMI/SMA
    branch[1].Departement = MATH;
    branch[1].Year = second;

            //SMF/SMA
    branch[2].Departement = MATH;
    branch[2].Year = licence;

            //MASTER-MATH
    branch[3].Departement = MATH;
    branch[3].Year = master;

            //DOCTURAT-MATH
    branch[4].Departement = MATH;
    branch[4].Year = doc;
/*=============-MATH-=============*/
/*<--------------SETUP-------------->*/ 
#include "base.h"
void set_students(_STUDENT* student)
{
    puts("Enter the Full name");
    scanf("%s", student->Stud_name);
    puts("Enter his deg");
        for(int k=0; k < DEG_SIZE; ++k){
            printf("deg[%d]", k+1);
                scanf("%f",student->deg[k]);
            puts("");
        }// end for
    puts("enter the year");
        scanf("%s", student->Stud_year);
    Stud_branch -> branch[2];
puts("DONE!");
}// end set_students()
```

> **af.c**

```
#include "base.h"

/*beginning of main()*/
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    _STUDENT Student;
    set_students(&Student);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}//end main()
```

## compiling..

```
[ar.lnx@new-host src-new] $ make
gcc -I.   -c -o af.o af.c
gcc -I.   -c -o student.o student.c
student.c: In function ‘set_students’:
student.c:23:25: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  student->Payment_State = hold;
                         ^
Building the application core..
gcc -o x af.o student.o -I.
Finish.
[ar.lnx@new-host src-new] $
```

## executing

```
[ar.lnx@new-host src-new] $ ./x
10
Enter the Full name
anas
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
[ar.lnx@new-host src-new] $
```

I'm trying for two days to fix this problem, can anyone help me understand where is the problem and how to fix it

Comment: student.c is not complete.  In particular, I don't see the line of code that produced the warning.

Comment: Identifiers starting with `_` and an uppercase letter are reserved by the standard. **Do not use them in application code.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The very first problem is in

```
  scanf("%s", student->Stud_name);
```

in your case, `Stud_name` is a `char` which is not sufficient to hold a *string*, (let alone you missed to pass the address part). You need an array there.

Attempt to read a *string* into a `char` with `%s` format specifier invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Try to change the definition of `Stud_name` from

```
char Stud_name;
```

to

```
#define NAMESIZ 32
. . . . 
char Stud_name[NAMESIZ];
```

Then, coming to the point I left aside earlier, you need to pass the **address of the variable** to the `scanf()` as the argument to format specifier. Something like

```
 scanf("%f",&(student->deg[k]));
```

and so on.